# Python code follow the if statements

Tags: python, python-2.7

I can't seem to get the a == x[3] to run as it should in Python 2.7.  I enter in the correct number and it doesn't say the 'Congrats' I told it to say if the statement was correct.
Also, how can I make repeat ten times instead of having to copy and paste the code ten times.  Thanks so much in advance!

```
import time
import random
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46,47,48,49,50]
print "WELCOME TO THE BEST GUESSING GAME IN THE WORLD!  GUESS THE RIGHT NUMBER AND YOU WIN A BRAND-NEW CAR"
random.shuffle(x)
time.sleep(2)
print "YOU GET 10 TRIES"
time.sleep(1)
print "GOOD LUCK!"
time.sleep(2)
a = raw_input('Enter number 1-50 ')
time.sleep(2)
if a == x[3]:
    print 'Congrats'
else:
    print 'NO' 
a = raw_input('Enter number 1-50 ')
time.sleep(2)
if a == x[3]:
    print 'Congrats'
else:
    print 'NO' 
a = raw_input('Enter number 1-50 ')
time.sleep(2)
if a == x[3]:
    print 'Congrats'
else:
    print 'NO' 
a = raw_input('Enter number 1-50 ')
time.sleep(2)
if a == x[3]:
    print 'Congrats'
else:
    print 'NO' 
a = raw_input('Enter number 1-50 ')
time.sleep(2)
if a == x[3]:
    print 'Congrats'
else:
    print 'NO' 
a = raw_input('Enter number 1-50 ')
time.sleep(2)
if a == x[3]:
    print 'Congrats'
else:
    print 'NO' 
a = raw_input('Enter number 1-50 ')
time.sleep(2)
if a == x[3]:
    print 'Congrats'
else:
    print 'NO' 
a = raw_input('Enter number 1-50 ')
time.sleep(2)
if a == x[3]:
    print 'Congrats'
else:
    print 'NO' 
a = raw_input('Enter number 1-50 ')
time.sleep(2)
if a == x[3]:
    print 'Congrats'
else:
    print 'NO' 
a = raw_input('Enter number 1-50 ')
time.sleep(2)
if a == x[3]:
    print 'Congrats'
else:
    print 'NO'
    a = raw_input('Enter number 1-50 ')
time.sleep(2)
if a == x[3]:
    print 'Congrats'
else:
    print 'NO'
time.sleep(1)
print 'YOU FAILED!!'
print x[3]
```

Comment: For having it repeat ten times, use a [for loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).

Comment: Also, instead of using an array of 50 numbers, you can use [x = random.randint(1, 50)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`raw_input` is going to return a string.  you'll need to convert it to an int first!  use `int(raw_input('...'))`.

also, `int()` crashes when you feed it things that it cannot cast to strings, so you may want to surround it with a `try/catch` statement that deals with improper inputs to prevent unexpected crashes.

you can use a `for` loop to avoid copy-pasting code.  if you're new to computer science and are learning python, check out the very popular [Learn Python the Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/).

Comment: How would I kill the program if I got it right?

Comment: Place ``exit()`` on the line after ``print 'Congrats'``

Answer (score 1):

Your `raw_input` is `str`. Make it into `int`, for example:

```
 a = int(raw_input('Enter number 1-50 '))
```